# Need a refresher a cross product problem

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I am doing some review on cross products, and I forgot how do a cross product similar to this:

$$vQ \times  B_1 = vQ \times B_2$$

where $Q,B_1,B_2$ are vectors, $\times$ is cross product, and $v$ is a scalar.

I would be trying to prove that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are equal to each other, other than saying that it is indeed true, but I don't know if an "inverse" cross product exists, and can't seem to figure out how to prove it exists, if it does. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Your problem is not quantified, so it is impossible to answer. Does this equality holds for a specific $Q$? for a specific $v$? For all $v$ and a specific $Q$ ? etc...

Comment: @GreginGre My understanding is that v is some scalar constant that is the same on both sides. Q is some vector that is the same on both sides. It's kind of hard to understand since I am not given any numbers, and I have to solve symbolically.

Comment: @GreginGre it seems clear to me.  If $v$ is a (*nonzero*) scalar, $Q$ is a (*nonzero vector*) and $B_1,B_2$ are both vectors, prove that $vQ\times B_1 = vQ\times B_2$ implies that $B_1=B_2$.  Given the context, it seems safe to assume we are specifically referring to the cross product in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @Integrand No this was all. I thought I remember from a class that my professor showed it would be true but said it wasn't important but it came up on practice problems, and won't answer questions about them since final is next week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be using JMoravitz's interpretation of the problem.

Suppose for every nonzero scalar $v$ and nonzero vector $Q$ we have $vQ\times B_1 = v Q \times B_2$. Then
$$
vQ\times B_1 - v Q \times B_2= \vec{0}
$$
$$
v\left(Q\times B_1 -  Q \times B_2\right)= \vec{0}
$$
$$
v\left(Q\times \big( B_1 - B_2\big)\right)= \vec{0}
$$Since $Q\neq \vec{0}$, there's only one vector that crosses with any vector to yield $\vec{0}$, namely $\vec{0}$. Then $B_1-B_2=\vec{0}$.

Comment: My interpretation was that we weren't actually talking about "for every $v,Q$" in which case you were right that it was false.  (*Consider the cross product between $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ in comparison to the cross product between $\vec{i}$ and $(\vec{i}+\vec{j})$.  If it were the case that we were talking about for every $v,Q$, then the above is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted your comment and OP's question in the best way I could.

Comment: This looks very familiar to me, and I think my professor did something nearly similar. I always seem to forget simple things like moving one side of an equation to the other side like you did. Thank you, this answers my question.